# Simple submodules of $\Bbb{C}S_4$-module $\Bbb{C}S_4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

We know that $\Bbb{C}S_4\cong \Bbb{C}\oplus \Bbb{C}\oplus M_{2}(\Bbb{C})\oplus M_{3}(\Bbb{C})\oplus M_{3}(\Bbb{C})$ as a $\Bbb{C}$-algebra.

I decomposed it into a direct sum of simple $\Bbb{C}S_4$-submodules.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Bbb{C}S_4
&\cong& \Bbb{C}\oplus \Bbb{C}\oplus M_{2}(\Bbb{C})\oplus M_{3}(\Bbb{C})\oplus M_{3}(\Bbb{C})\\
&\cong& \Bbb{C}\oplus \Bbb{C}\oplus M_{2}(\Bbb{C})E_{11}^{(2)}\oplus M_{2}(\Bbb{C})E_{22}^{(2)}\\
&\oplus& M_{3}(\Bbb{C})E_{11}^{(3)}\oplus M_{3}(\Bbb{C})E_{22}^{(3)}\oplus M_{3}(\Bbb{C})E_{33}^{(3)}\\
&\oplus&  M_{3}(\Bbb{C})E_{11}^{(3)}\oplus M_{3}(\Bbb{C})E_{22}^{(3)}\oplus M_{3}(\Bbb{C})E_{33}^{(3)},
\end{eqnarray*}
where $E_{ii}^{(j)}$ is the $j\times j$ matrix with $1$ at the $(i,i)$-position and $0$ elsewhere.

I think $M_{3}(\Bbb{C})E_{11}^{(3)}\cong M_{3}(\Bbb{C})E_{22}^{(3)}\cong M_{3}(\Bbb{C})E_{33}^{(3)}$ as a simple $\Bbb{C}S_4$-module.
So there is only one irreducible representation (up to equivalent) of degree $3$ and only one irreducible character of degree $3$.
However, there are **TWO** irreducible characters of degree $3$ of $S_4$.

**Where is the problem in my argument?**
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sure, the ones coming from the same copy of $M_3$ are isomorphic. But the ones from different copies are not.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I can't prove that the ones from different copies are not isomorphic. Could you please give me an example?

Comment: You have that decomposition on your third line. The summands are also minimal 2-sided ideals of $\Bbb{C}S_4$ (this is the case with all Wedderburn decompositions). Implying that the two copies of $M_3(\Bbb{C})$ annihilate each other (and act in the obvious way on themselves). Does that not make it clear that they are not isomorphic as $\Bbb{C}S_4$-modules?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry. I still can't understand. For an easier example, $R=M_2(\Bbb{C})\oplus M_2(\Bbb{C})
\cong M_2(\Bbb{C})E_{11}^{(2)}\oplus M_2(\Bbb{C})E_{22}^{(2)}
\oplus M_2(\Bbb{C})E_{11}^{(2)}\oplus M_2(\Bbb{C})E_{22}^{(2)}$.
If $\theta:M_2(\Bbb{C})E_{11}^{(2)}\oplus 0\oplus 0\oplus 0\to 0\oplus 0\oplus M_2(\Bbb{C})E_{11}^{(2)}\oplus 0$ is an $R$-module isomorphism and $ab\neq 0$,

Comment: then $\theta(\left(\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}, 0, 0, 0\right)\left(\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\b&0\end{pmatrix}, 0, 0, 0\right))
=\theta(\left(\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\b&0\end{pmatrix}, 0, 0, 0\right))
=\left(0, 0, \begin{pmatrix}x&0\\y&0\end{pmatrix}, 0\right)\neq (0,0,0,0)
=\left(\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}, 0, 0, 0\right)
\cdot \theta(\left(\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\b&0\end{pmatrix}, 0, 0, 0\right))$.

Comment: So $M_2(\Bbb{C})E_{11}^{(2)}\oplus 0\oplus 0\oplus 0
\not\cong 0\oplus 0\oplus M_2(\Bbb{C})E_{11}^{(2)}\oplus 0$ as an $R$-module.
**But I can use the same way to prove that $M_2(\Bbb{C})E_{11}^{(2)}\oplus 0\oplus 0\oplus 0
\not\cong 0\oplus M_2(\Bbb{C})E_{22}^{(2)}\oplus 0\oplus 0$.
What is the mistake?**

Comment: To make it even simpler, consider $R=\Bbb{C}\oplus\Bbb{C}$. Let $M=\Bbb{C}^2$ be the left regular $R$-module, and $M_1=\{(z,0)\mid z\in\Bbb{C}\}$ and $M_2=\{(0,z)\mid z\in\Bbb{C}\}$ be the obvious irreducible submodules. Then $M_1$ and $M_2$ are not isomorphic as $R$-modules. For $(1,0)\in R$ acts like the identity on $M_1$, but it annihilates $M_2$. Any homomorphism of $R$-modules from $M_1$ to $M_2$ is thus constant zero

Comment: So there cannot be an isomorphism like your $\theta$. The element $(I_2,0_2)\in R$ acts as identity on $M_2(\Bbb{C})E_{11}\oplus0\oplus0\oplus0$ but it annihilates all of $0\oplus0\oplus M_2(\Bbb{C})E_{11}\oplus0$. The element $(0_2,I_2)\in R$ does the opposite.

Comment: Yet in other way: If $R=R_1\oplus R_2$ is a direct sum of ideals $R_1$ and $R_2$, and those ideals happen to be isomorphic as rings $R_1\simeq R_2$, it does not follow that they would be isomorphic as $R$-modules. Rather, it is trivially clear that they are not.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ok. I see. But why $M_2(\Bbb{C})E_{11}^{(2)}\oplus 0\oplus 0\oplus 0
\cong 0\oplus M_2(\Bbb{C})E_{22}^{(2)}\oplus 0\oplus 0$ as an $R$-module? As the first comment said. $M_2(\Bbb{C})E_{11}^{(2)}$ and $M_2(\Bbb{C})E_{22}^{(2)}$ are both from $M_2(\Bbb{C})$.

Comment: If $S=\pmatrix{0&1\cr 1&0\cr}$ then the mapping $\theta:(U,V)\mapsto (US,V)$ is a homomorphism of $R$-modules (again $U,V$ are arbitrary 2x2-matrices). $\theta$ intechanges those two summands, and it follows that it gives an isomorphism between them.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @JyrkiLahtonen comments.

I thought I got where my problem is. I should not write $R=M_2(\Bbb{C})\oplus M_2(\Bbb{C})
\cong M_2(\Bbb{C})E_{11}^{(2)}\oplus M_2(\Bbb{C})E_{22}^{(2)}
\oplus M_2(\Bbb{C})E_{11}^{(2)}\oplus M_2(\Bbb{C})E_{22}^{(2)}$.

This notation might cause a misunderstanding 
$M_2(\Bbb{C})E_{11}^{(2)}\oplus 0\oplus 0\oplus 0
\not\cong 
0\oplus 0\oplus M_2(\Bbb{C})E_{11}^{(2)}\oplus 0$
and
$M_2(\Bbb{C})E_{11}^{(2)}\oplus 0\oplus 0\oplus 0
\not\cong 
0\oplus M_2(\Bbb{C})E_{22}^{(2)}\oplus 0\oplus 0$
as $R$-modules.

I had better to write $$M_2(\Bbb{C})\oplus M_2(\Bbb{C})
\cong 
\left\{\left(\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\b&0\end{pmatrix}, 0\right)\right\}
\oplus 
\left\{\left(\begin{pmatrix}0&a\\0&b\end{pmatrix}, 0\right)\right\}
\oplus 
\left\{\left(0, \begin{pmatrix}a&0\\b&0\end{pmatrix}\right)\right\}
\oplus 
\left\{\left(0, \begin{pmatrix}0&a\\0&b\end{pmatrix}\right)\right\}$$